# set to zero row values lover than rowmean

Tags: r, dataframe, row, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 
 4   1  3  4  3
 2   2  2  1  1
 2   10 2  1  2
 etc.
```

I want to transform the dataframe such that just raw values higher than raw mean are kept and the others are set to zero
result would be:

```
 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 
 4   0  3  4  3
 2   2  2  0  0
 0   10 0  0  0
 etc.
```

I tried something like this but it doesnt work (X is the dataframe):

```
X<- X[sweep(X, 1, rowMeans(X) < 0)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```
(df > rowMeans(df)) * df

  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  4  0  0  4  0
2  2  2  2  0  0
3  0 10  0  0  0
```

Comment: you mean df<- df[df < rowMeans(df)] * 0 ?

Comment: I don't think so. I keep just the values higher than the row mean, all the other are set to zero.

Comment: oh you re right, it works, i made a typo when using your formula, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Using `sweep` you could have done :

```
df[sweep(df, 1, rowMeans(df), `<`)] <- 0
df

#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1  4  0  3  4  3
#2  2  2  2  0  0
#3  0 10  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `replace`

```
replace(X, X <= rowMeans(X), 0)
#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1  4  0  0  4  0
#2  2  2  2  0  0
#3  0 10  0  0  0
```

#### data

```
X <- structure(list(v1 = c(4L, 2L, 2L), v2 = c(1L, 2L, 10L), v3 = c(3L, 
2L, 2L), v4 = c(4L, 1L, 1L), v5 = c(3L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```